# Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Could not find any recognizable digits

Tags: error, list-definition

Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Could not find any recognizable digits.

Dos anyone know what this error message means? I'm trying to deploy a feature containing some, content types, list definitions and list instances.

[image: Output in Error List]

Comment: how about uls logs?

Comment: Ditto the ULS logs, but also, what was the feature? Built in or third party?

Comment: Thanks for your help guys! I friend helped me solve it. Quite stupid to not think of the GUID that cant contain anything else then "hexadecimal-digits".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurred because of a GUID that had a invalid character. >.<

Comment: I hope you aren't typing a GUID by hand? You know you can use [visual studio to generate a GUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241442%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)?

Comment: No, I used the GUID tool, but then did do some changes, trying to make a simple system organizing the GUId's.